# Tool for generating optimized, reduced CSS rule sets

Tags: css

Let's pretend that I am using a CSS library (e.g. Bootstrap) that has its own CSS files together with a custom theme.

In Bootstrap's CSS, there might be a rule like this:

```
.foo {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 4px;
}
```

And in my custom theme, `.foo` is overridden as:

```
.foo {
   border-color: red;
   border-width: 2px;
}
```

The effective, computed rule is gonna be:

```
.foo {
   border: 2px solid red;
   padding: 4px;
}
```

Is there a tool that given a set of one or more CSS files, can produce this reduced, minimized, effective CSS output?

Comment: why would u want this? you defined a class, and if necessary, you override it.

Comment: This has the effect that it is going to be overriden for the whole website. So if I only had the third rule, everything would still work as before, but the size of the CSS would get reduced.

Comment: if you want to override, you can just change bootstrap's library rather than attempting to merge (you should know which classes you're trying to change)

Comment: This is not practical. For example when you want to use the Flat UI theme: http://designmodo.com/flat-free/